# ModelBuilder Run Time Errors Using ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I recently susccesfully ran a watershed delineation model using both ArcHydro Tools for Arc GIS 10.0 and Model Builder in ArcGIS 10.0 on Windows 7 system (`Dell Inspiron N4110 Intel Core TM i3 CPU @ 2.30 GHz 64 Bit.`)

However when I try to run the same model on an XP computer (`Intel Pentium 4 CPU @ 2.53 GHz 32 Bit`) I received several run time errors such as:

- Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. Fail to execute (Catchment Polygon Processing)" and also other like
- Drainage Point.. All the inputs are not current
- Adjoint Catchment All the inputs are not current

I try also to build the same model from the scratch in this later system and I received the same type of run time errors.  I'd be pleased to receive any clue to fix this problem.